# android EditText does not expand to mutiple lines when set android:inputType

Tags: android, android-edittext

I used a EditText widget to contain contacts. The layout file is as below

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_name_editor"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add_recipients"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar_in_new_chat"
        android:hint="Recipients"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

It works fine, the default line is 1 and when many contacts are filled in, it will expand to 3 lines and scroll.
Then I changed it to the following(just added a `android:inputType="number|text"` attribute):

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/contact_name_editor"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/add_recipients"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="3dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dip"
        android:background="@drawable/search_bar_in_new_chat"
        android:hint="Recipients"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingRight="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:paddingBottom="3dip"
        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
        android:maxLines="3"
        android:inputType="number|text"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:editable="true"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />
```

Then it failed expanding, just keep single line.

Why setting the inputType blocks the `EditText` expanding?

Comment: i don't know why you are adding that number parameter to it? Text input can take numbers as well.

Comment: use android:singleLine="false"

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried?

```
android:inputType="number|textMultiLine"
```

If above will not work then you can use:

```
android:numeric="integer"
```

This will work definitely but let me clear this is deprecated now. But for your problem this is the only solution available what I found.